# Agent role isn't permitted to edit users

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

In "App Store Connect -> Users and Access" I'm trying to add an app to some user.

When I'm trying to save changes I get error:

"Your account doesn’t have permission to edit other users. Contact your team agent for more information."

The problem is that I'm the admin in App Store Connect and agent in the corresponding apple developer program account.

Comment: That's strange. Are you sure that you are the Admin and Agent on the developer account? How many other members are you seeing, while clicking on People section at developer.apple.com?

Comment: Pretty sure. It's individual account, not enterprise. So there's no People section at developer.apple.com. But in App Store Connect there are about 15 users in Users and Access section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so in order add permissions for some app to a user I've needed to change his/her role then return previous role and after that add the app. It allowed me to save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout for your role under the `People` Section of the developer account.

1. Login to [Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/account/)
2. Click on **People** tab on right side.
3. Checkout your role and see, if you are agent and admin for that team.

Possible reason for this to happen is:

You are having multiple developer account or some one has added you as the admin to their team. And when you tries to login with your developer id and password, you may be redirected to that team, in which you role as admin only.

So, choose the appropriate team by clicking the right down arrow, besides your Name in https://appstoreconnect.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Must be a bug, 
if you un-check and re-check user role at same time you adding new apps bypass the permissions.

I believe should be Apple reported.